# Disabling sounds/beeps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, noise

Is there any way to disable, mute, or otherwise change the incessant message 'beep' in QGIS?

I need volume on the PC for other unrelated notifications.

Comment: What operating system are you using? You can usually disable noises at the system level.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Left-click on the volume icon in the bottom right corner of your screen (assuming Windows). Click on Mixer. You will see a list of applications that are currently open and that play sounds, like so:

[image]

Drag the sound slider to the bottom and you're done.

If you don't see your application in the Mixer, it hasn't made a sound since it has been opened. In this case, just trigger a sound (e.g. try using the open vector dialog with no contents). Re-open the Mixer and the application should be present.

Comment: Many thanks. So simple a solution I completely overlooked it.

Comment: @mastorey If this solved your problem then you might want to accept Radar's answer by clicking the check sign :)