# Disable sound associated with layer removal, keeping other sounds in QGIS

Tags: qgis, windows, user-interface

Using QGIS 3.26 on Windows 10.

Is there a way to prevent playing a sound when removing a layer from the canvas?

[image]

The sound might be associated with the confirmation dialog, so maybe any confirmation will be affected, which seems anyway a sensible choice.

[image]

(Playing a sound any time a user must confirm a non-reversible action, not distinguishing between harmless usual actions from an abnormal situation, has been recognized since a long time as counterproductive.)

The question is about the association action-sound in QGIS, not about [adjusting audio volume per application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/38893/201000) or not asking for confirmation.

Comment: "*A community member has suggested a similar question that may solve your problem*", please don't suggest a question I explicitly mentioned and indicated being a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Unchecking `Prompt for confrmajon when а lауег is to bе removed` in the `Settings` => `Options` => tab `General`.
2. Disable notifications sound in your OS (how to do that in [Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/turn-off-change-windows-10-notification-sounds/)).

[image]

Comment: In my question: "***The question is** about the association action-sound in QGIS, **not about** adjusting audio volume per application or **not asking for confirmation**.*"

Comment: @mins As far as I know it is impossible without changing the source code of QGIS. It might be worth creating an appropriate feature request.